¿Cómo hacer que calcule el cuadrado de un numero en ensamblador 8086?
Debo hacer un programa que reciba un numero y lo muestre al cuadrado, pero el codigo que tengo no ejecuta: Programa para calcular el cuadrado de un número en ensamblador 8086
.model small
.stack 100h

.data
    numero dw 0
    cuadrado dw 0

.code
main proc
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ; Pide al usuario que ingrese el número
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    sub al, 30h ; convierte de ASCII a binario
    mov numero, ax

    ; Calcula el cuadrado
    mov ax, numero
    mul ax       ; multiplicación sin signo
    mov cuadrado, ax

    ; Imprime el resultado
    mov dx, offset mensaje
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov ax, cuadrado
    add ax, 30h   ; convierte de binario a ASCII
    mov dx, ax
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h

main endp

mensaje db 'El cuadrado del numero es: $'

end main

alguien me podría ayudar para que pueda calcular el cuadrado de un numero recibido por el usuario

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! programacion funcional no tiene nada que ver con esto... depuracion tampoco.. cual es el error que recibis al ejecutar? como lo estas ejecutando??

Hola @Karen, Tu código es para MS-DOS. ¿Cómo lo estás ejecutando?, en dosbox?. vdos? Para un programa como este lo más sencillo es general un .COM que debería tener un org 100h al principio. La forma de generarlo dependerá de tu entorno de desarrollo, ensamblador, etc... Si nos das más detalles quizás podamos ayudarte más

Lo de sumar solo sirve para un dígito. Si planeas mostrar todos los dígitos el algoritmo será un poco más largo
